# Javascript com async-await

Tags: javascript, mysql, mvc, async-await

Estou usando async-await na função de consulta SQL na Model e uso o padrão MVC. O problema é que ao executar a função (select SQL) na model ela é executada mas o retorno é: [object Object] , como se o resultado fosse indefinido. A aplicação não apresenta erro mas não volta para o controller onde tenho outro console.log para monitorar o retorno.
Abaixo parte do código.

arquivo routes.js

```
const segurosRoutes = require('../controllers/segurosControllers.js');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/estagio/movimentacoes/cadastroSeguros', segurosRoutes.segurosGetAll);
}
```

arquivo controllers.js

```
const segurosController = require('../models/segurosModels.js');
 
module.exports = {
    segurosGetAll,
}


function segurosGetAll(req, res){
    console.log("Entrando em Controllers Seguros: ")
    segurosController.getAll(function (err, result){
        if(err) {
            console.log("Erro: " + err)
            throw err;
        }else{
            console.log("Resultado "+result)            
        }
    })
}
```

arquivo models.js

```
const client = require('../../config/conexao.js');
 
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
  getAll,
}  
 
async function getAll() {

  m_sql = 'select A.*, B.seg_razaosocial, B.seg_nomefantasia, C.alu_nome, D.usu_username from seguros A left join seguradora B on A.seg_codigo = B.seg_codigo left join usuarios D on A.usu_codigo = D.usu_codigo left join alunos C on A.alu_codigo = C.alu_codigo ';

  console.log("SQL em Seguros...."+m_sql)
  console.log("-----------------------")
  let retorno

  try{
    const retorno = await client.query(m_sql)
    console.log("Retornando da SQL: "+retorno)
  } catch(erro) {
    console.log(erro)
    retorno  = erro
  }

  return retorno

}
```

No terminal:

```
Express executando na porta. 3000
Entrando em Controllers Seguros: 
SQL em Seguros....select A.*, B.seg_razaosocial, B.seg_nomefantasia, C.alu_nome, D.usu_username from seguros A left join seguradora B on A.seg_codigo = B.seg_codigo left join usuarios D on A.usu_codigo = D.usu_codigo left join alunos C on A.alu_codigo = C.alu_codigo
```

Retornando da SQL: [object Object]

Comment: Não crie perguntas duplicadas de uma sua que já foi fechada ([MVC Javascript+async await](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478571/mvc-javascriptasync-await)). Prefira melhorar a pergunta original do que abrir outra.

Answer (score -3):

Quando o javascript retorna [object Object] é porque ele esta printando a instancia do objeto.
Pra resolver isso, vc pode usar  o metodo JSON.stringify() pra mostrar o conteudo da sua variavel, assim ele converte o seu objeto em string.

Nesse caso ficaria:
console.log("Retornando da SQL: "+ JSON.stringify(retorno))